# How do I fix my Database Script from not updating to add additional data in to the next Row when Command Button is pressed?

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a database script I am making with an excel UserForm for my hospital but for some reason when I click on the Add Patient button after already adding a patient it wont go to the next empty row to enter a new patient. It stays on the same row unless I close the UserForm and reopen it then it enters new data into the next row but still doesnt update to go to the next row to add new data. Below is the code for the add patient button also the link to my excel document. I dont know what I am missing and maybe I just need a second set of eyes.

[Excel Document](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wkxF-O4HY00B1623JqEs-28vc8aHOTqM/view?usp=sharing)

```
Private Sub cmdAddPatient_Click()
    With Me
        'check the caption
        If .cmdAddPatient.Caption = "Add Patient" Then
            'rData has been defined so to get the row to add data we just need to count the Rows in that Range & add 1
            lRw = rData.Rows.Count + 1
        End If
        'because we have declared rData as a Range we can actually treat it as we would aA WORKSHHEET, _
         So, rData.Cells(1,1) refers to the first cell in the Range, i.e. A5
        For iX = 1 To iCol
            rData.Cells(lRw, iX).Value = Me("txt" & iX).Value
            Me("txt" & iX).Value = Empty
        Next iX
        'autofit the columns of Data
        rData.Columns.AutoFit
        'update data range
        Set rData = Sheet1.Range("A5").CurrentRegion
        'Set rData = Sheet1.Cells(lOffset, 1).CurrentRegion
        .lstInfo.Clear
        .lstInfo.List = Sheet1.Range("A5").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Value
        .txt1.Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(rData.Columns(1)) + 1
        .Hide
        .cmdAddPatient.Caption = "Add Data"
        .Show
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I changed .cmdAddPatient.Caption = "Add Data" to.cmdAddPatient.Caption = "Add Patient" so I could press the button repeatably and records were added on a new row each time which suggests the problem might be in another part of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looked at your spreadsheet.. At the end of your code you change the caption for your button:

```
.cmdAddPatient.Caption = "Add Data"
```

So when the code runs again the button says "Add Data" so these lines never trigger to set the last row as the next row..

```
If .cmdAddPatient.Caption = "Add Patient" Then
        'rData has been defined so to get the row to add data we just need to count the Rows in that Range & add 1
        lRw = rData.Rows.Count + 1
    End If
```